# How to schedule a Jenkins job every 3 hours but exclude a certain time frame

Tags: jenkins, cron

I want to schedule a jenkins job every 3 hours but exclude 6 o'clock. Something like the following statement which unfortunately is not possible in Jenkins:

```
H (0-5,7-23)/3 * * *
```

If I use the following statement it is treated separately:

```
H 0-5/3,7-23/3 * * *
```

Hence, the job starts at 0 o'clock even if the previous job was executed at 22 o'clock.
The worst solution would be to specify all times manually. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicitly set the hours.

So if you want to skip 6 PM then Jenkins corn will be

```
H 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23 * * *
```

and if you want skip 6 AM then

```
H 0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * *
```